# How to pass my hidden primary key value in a gridview to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have technically 5 columns in a gridview

1. EDIT and Deactivate button
2. Name
3. Phone
4. Email
5. [Hidden] userid "which is my primary key on the table"

I want to pass this userid value of the selected row to my update stored procedure that will  set active=0 where userid=@userid.

Not sure if there is a way to pass a selecteddatakey or pass only the selected row hidden column 4 which would be 5 in index or if you have any other better ways.

```
protected void gvRowDeleting2(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_update_user_active";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userID; ******NEED HELP HERE****

    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        buildcontractoradmingv();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        /*Display message saying company is deactivated*/
        string message = "User has been removed";
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += message;
        script += "')};";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: See if it's in [`e.Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeleteeventargs.values(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`e.Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeleteeventargs.keys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
string UserID = YourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[IndexOfHiddenCol].Text;
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked "string UserID = YourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;

Comment: No prob mate :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add `userID` as `DataKeyNames` to the GridView. `userID` in this case is a database column or property of the source bound to the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="userID"
```

Then get the value from the DataKeys in the delete method.

```
int userID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
```

Or you can add a `Label` to the `TemplateField` with the Visibility set to `false`.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

And then get the value in code behind by using `FindControl` to look for the label and read it's Text.

```
Label label = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
int userID = Convert.ToInt32(label.Text);
```

Comment: Hi I tried the first method and got this message. "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"  what does the 0 in values[0] refer too? I will try the second way and report back

Comment: Did you add `DataKeyNames` to the GridView?

Comment: yes I did. I tried both methods and still have the same issue. Does this work for a hidden column?would you like to see more code?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowEditing="gvRowEdit2" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="gvRowCancelingEdit2" 
    OnRowDeleting="gvRowDeleting2" 
    OnRowUpdating="gvRowUpdating2" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView2RowDataBound" 
    DataKeyNames="userid">

Comment: I used the code in the answer below and It worked. Thank you for taking the time out to help